JMeter. Remove field and modify from JSON request body
I would like to alter the json request prior processing. The following is my condition:

If any field has a value of null. removed the field.
If any field has a value of "emptyString". field value will be change to empty string.

Json Request:
{
    "seId": "${seId}",
    "usr": "${usr}",
    "transactionDetails": {
        "tType": ${ttionType},
        "note": "${Test_Project}"
    },
    "isOtp": true
}

Module Controller>HTTP Request>JSR223 PreProcessor
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

// Get the request body as a string
def requestBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()

// Parse the request body JSON
def objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
def json = objectMapper.readTree(requestBody)

// Iterate over JSON fields
json.fields().each { field ->
    // Check if field value is null and remove the field
    if (field.value.isNull()) {
        log.info("Removing field '${field.key}' because its value is null.")
        json.remove(field.key)
    } else {
        // Identify specific field values and take actions
        def value = field.value.textValue()
        switch (value) {
            case "emptyString":
                log.info("Replacing value of field '${field.key}' with empty string.")
                json.put(field.key, "")
                break
            // Add more cases as needed for other actions
            default:
                // Do nothing for other values
                log.info("No action taken for field '${field.key}' with value '${value}'.")
                break
        }
    }
}

// Set the modified and formatted request body
def modifiedBody = json.toPrettyString()
sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(modifiedBody)


In this code, I keep on going into the default. I have a parameter controller and field value is declare on then just calling a module controller. So I have a parameterize json request.

Take a look at jmeter.log file, if JSR223 PreProcessor fails (and my expectation is that it fails) you
A cannot reproduce your issue using the following CSV file:
1,emptyString,3,4
5,6,7,8
emptyString,9,10,11

the following CSV Data Set Config setup:

and your code without any changes in the JSR223 PreProcessor:

